# Probability and (probably) combinatorics problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem is as follows. 
"There are 27 students on the college debate team. What is the probability that AT LEAST 3 of them have their birthdays in the same month?"

I have been fumbling with it for a while and still not sure if my solution is correct. I use the binomial distribution to find the probabilities of getting exactly $ \bf x $ number of successes (say, the month of January) in a series of 27 "trials" (i.e. team members). I use the formula:

$$ \text { the probability of getting at least 3 same months =  }{27 \choose x}{p^x}{(1-p)^{27-x}} $$
for $ {x \in \{3,...,27\}} $

I get probabilities p(x=3), p(x=4), ..., p(x=27), sum them and I should get the probability of getting at least 3 members in a team of 27 whose birth months are the same. My quick R code

```
n = 27
p <- as.numeric(NULL)
pSuccess = 1/12
for (x in seq(0, n, by=1)){
  p <- append (p, (factorial(n)/(factorial(x)*factorial(n-x))) * pSuccess^x * (1-pSuccess)^(n-x))
}
barplot(p)
print(sum(p[4:28]))
```

gives me 0.3934734

However, the answer key says different: the probability is 1. How is that possible? Please help.

Comment: $1{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: If they didn't, at most two would have been born in January, at most two would have been born in February, at most two would have been born in March....  can you see where I'm going with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, we can find the answer without too much calculation.  There are 27 students and only twelve months.

If we want as little overlap as possible, then we can imagine that the first twelve students we check have birthdays on all different months, then the next twelve students have birthdays on different months.

We have checked twenty-four students and now in the worst case have 2 students for each month. The twenty-fifth student, whatever their birth month, will make it so that one month has at least three students.

Hence, it's unavoidable to have at least three students share the same birth month.

Comment: Ok. I see now. Then what's wrong with my "formulaic" approach? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I believe your formula computes the probability that for a pre-selected month, at least three people have a birthday during that month (e.g. the probability that at least three people have birthdays in January). Instead you want the month not to be specified in advance, which makes the outcome more likely.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case for the pigeonhole-principle :

If we have $\color\green {24}$ students, the only way to avoid that $3$ have their birthday at the same month is that for every month we have two students with their birthday in that month.

So, if we have $\color\red {25}$ or more students, $3$ students with the same birth-month cannot be avoided.